# Probability of matching piece and square colours in random chess laydown

Tags: probability, combinatorics, chessboard

I have an 8x8 chess board and place my 32 pieces randomly on the board (ignoring any chess rules). What is the probability that every piece is on a square that matches its colour?

My attempt:

I have to choose 32 squares on which to place my pieces. This can be done in ${64 \choose 32}$ ways. But for each set I choose I can place my pieces in $32!$ ways so the total number of ways to place my pieces is
$${64 \choose 32}32!$$

I need the number of white squares I choose to equal the number of black squares (i.e. 16 of each). How many ways can I choose that satisfy this requirement? I don't think I care about order so I'll choose my 16 black squares first and then my 16 white squares. I can choose the first black square in 32 ways, the second in 31 ways ... the 16th in 17 ways, then I do the same for the white squares. So the total number of ways with equal numbers of black and white squares is
$$\left(\frac{32!}{16!}\right)^2$$.

Assuming all black pieces are identical (likewise for white) there is only one way to place my pieces so that the colours match. Therefore the overall probability is
$$\frac{\left(\frac{32!}{16!}\right)^2}{{64 \choose 32}32!}$$

I'm not confident if this is right because I get hopelessly confused in combinatorics with when I should assumed things are identical, and whether I've double counted something.

Comment: "there is only one way to place my pieces so that the colours match", are you sure about this?

Comment: @MikeHawk If all pieces of the same colour are identical, then I think so. But like I said these things hurt my brain.

Comment: Perhaps I have misread the question, but it seems to me that if there are, say, two white pieces and two white squares, then there are two different ways to place the pieces on the square (piece 1 on square 1 and piece 2 on square 2 vs piece 1 on square 2 and piece 2 on square 1)

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: @MikeHawk If I labelled my pieces then, yes. But I'm treating them as identical. I am doing the same when I count the ways to get 16 white and 16 black squares. I think this is okay. If I labelled them then I think a common factor would cancel out between the square counting and the piece counting and I would get the same result. Considerations like this are what cause me to ask the question because I'm never sure if I've counted things consistently.

Comment: ok, if the pieces of a given color are regarded as identical then what you wrote looks correct to me, and i agree about the common factor cancelling as well. i would recommend revising the problem statement to make it clear whether the pieces are to be regarded as labeled or unlabeled. on the one hand, assuming they are unlabeled seems strange since there are several different kinds of chess pieces. on the other hand, if one assumes the pieces are labeled, then it is jarring to see "assuming all black pieces are identical" in the proof, without some extra justification like you have just given